# Create new object inside inside Collectors.mapper loop?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this code:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, List<RollingField>>> fieldMap = rollingFields.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RollingField::getDate,
                Collectors.groupingBy(fi -> fi.getMeta().getName())));
```

And i have method `rollingFieldsToRollingDTO` which doing from List to ShortRollingFieldDTO

How can i create it with Collectors.mapping? Now i have idea like:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<ShortRollingFieldDTO>> rollingFieldFrontDTOS = rollingFields.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractField::getDate,
              Collectors.mapping(rf -> new ShortRollingFieldDTO(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: input `Set<RollingField> rollingFields`, expected `Map<LocalDate, List<ShortRollingFieldDTO>`

Comment: @aliliab4a12 - Please share the code for RollingField, DTOs etc.